# URL Links is UiTableView with multiple sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, url

I have created a UiTableViewController with four sections and a number of rows in each. I have also implemented an array of URLs. I am new to coding and this is a combination of work on two previous TableViewControllers, but the problem I am having is that the URL array applies to each section. i.e. when clicking row 1 in section 1 it opens the first link, but it also opens the first link when clicking row 1 in section 2.

How do I limit the URL array to just one section?

I understand why it isn't working, and have tried lots of things, but not got it so far.

```
struct Objects {
    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects :[String]!
}

var objectsArray = [Objects]()

let urlArray1 = ["http://www.apple.co.uk","http://www.google.co.uk","https://www.dropbox.com/","tel://123456789",""]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    objectsArray = [Objects(sectionName: "Section 1", sectionObjects: ["one", "two", "three", "four","four A"]),
                    Objects(sectionName: "Section 2", sectionObjects: ["five", "six", "seven", "eight"]),
                    Objects(sectionName: "Section 3", sectionObjects: ["nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve"]),
                    Objects(sectionName: "Section 4", sectionObjects: ["thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen"])]
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as UITableViewCell!

    cell?.textLabel?.text = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]

    return cell!
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objectsArray[section].sectionObjects.count
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return objectsArray.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return objectsArray[section].sectionName
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let urlString = self.urlArray1[indexPath.row]
    if let  url = URL(string:urlString)
    {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `urlArray1` needs to be set up into separate sections.

When you call `let urlString = self.urlArray1[indexPath.row]` it only depends on the row, not the section. So (section 0, row 0), (section 1, row 0), (section 2, row 0), etc. all return the same value.

I would add a URL property to your `Object` struct:

```
struct Objects {
    var sectionName: String
    var sectionObjects: [String]
    var urlStrings: [String]
}
```

And then you can access the appropriate one like so:

```
let urlString = objectsArray[indexPath.section].urlStrings[indexPath.row]
```

(make sure to define the `urlStrings` in your `objectsArray`)